# Можно ли в Qt из pro файла выдрать VERSION?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Можно ли в Qt из pro файла выдрать VERSION? И потом использовать его как константу например.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно добавить `VERSION` в `DEFINES`.

pro:

```
VERSION = 1.2.3
DEFINES += VERSION=\\\"$$VERSION\\\"
```

cpp:

```
qDebug() << VERSION;
```

вывод:

```
1.2.3
```

Comment: Спс все работает