# Как создать константу в .pro файле?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Лучше чтобы ее видно было во всем проекте, но в принципе можно чтобы она работала и только в .pro файле *Qt*. Мне это надо для удобства подключения библиотек. Пробовал так:

```
DEFINES += PUTH_TO_CV_LIB = "\G:\qt\opencv\build\bin\\"
LIBS += PUTH_TO_CV_LIB+libopencv_core320.dll
```

выбрасывает ошибку:

> ```
> <command-line>:-1: ошибка: no macro name given in #define directive
> ```

Comment: А вам нужно чтобы и препроцессор/компилер этот макрос видели?

Comment: Я не знаю. Ну главное чтоб эту константу можно было использовать в самом pro файле для удобства, чтоб много раз тоже самое не писать

Comment: Можете прочитать руководство по qmake: http://blog.mgsxx.com/?page_id=1294

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вы ведь уже задавали такой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683563/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-qt-%D0%B8%D0%B7-pro-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-version/). Только теперь вместо `VERSION` вам нужна какая-то произвольная константа:
pro:

```
ANSWER = "42"
DEFINES += ANSWER=\\\"$$ANSWER\\\"
```

cpp:

```
qDebug() << "The answer is" << ANSWER;
```

вывод:

```
The answer is 42
```

Comment: С путями например ANSWER = "G:\qt\opencv\build\bin\" это не работает

Comment: @MadokaMagica экранируйте слэши и все наверняка будет работать.

Comment: А я кажется понял из-за чего не работало посл. слэш надо заэкранировать ну или без слэша: так ANSWER = "G:\qt\opencv\build\bin\\" Спс всем

Comment: @MadokaMagica, если ответ Вам помог, отметьте его как «верный», нажав на галочку рядом с ответом.